# write code that wrapped in <?php ?> tags to other page

Tags: php, html

i am working on a code that write code from an other page(default template page). the template page have some html and some php code. html contains some input fields and php code is used to take data from that fields and insert it into db table but the problem i am facing is that it only get html from the default page and write it into new generated page and skip all code that is surrounded by  tags.

here is the php code that is used  get code from default template page and write it on new generated page.

```
    if($aa){
       ob_end_clean();
       ob_start();
       include('test.php');
       $html = ob_get_contents();
       ob_end_clean();
       $ourFileName = $title.".php";
       file_put_contents($ourFileName, $html);
       fclose($ourFileHandle);
}
```

tesp.php contain code like that

```
       <?php 
       ...
       ...
       ...
       ?>
      <form....
      <input...
      <input...
      <input...
      </form>
```

i set test.php page as a template page so that all new generated page through above code should have this php and html code

but the out put is like that

```
      <form....
      <input...
      <input...
      <input...
      </form>
```

with missing php code. hope you guys could understand what i want to know.

Comment: Well it seems that the tags are missing because they were processed/parsed...or did what it had to do...you should give a better example to see the issue better...Are you saying that the piece of code didn't do anything?

Comment: no the code is working but it only grab html from the template page but what i want to do is to grab html as well as php code

Answer (score 0):

Rather than to include the php file you should **read the file line by line and write it in another place**...or just make a copy 
(I do not know what you are trying to accomplish). When you include the file whatever you have in the **tags get's processed and you see the end result**